# Check if column B contains a specific string that exists in column A and then remove it from the cell in column B

Tags: excel, vba

So I want either an excel function or VBA script that searches through column B for a specific string that exists in column A, and then once there's a match I want to remove that string from the cell in column B and return the rest of the cell contents into column C.

I can't use a simple "find and replace" because, as you can see in the picture, the text in each of the cells is in the form of an ID with an underscore followed by a random number appended to it.  And I have around 100,000 rows to search through.

An example table of what I'd like is shown below:

[image: Example table]

Comment: Find and replace would make this pretty easy

Comment: How would you do that if there's an underscore and random number appended to it?

Comment: Well that question is pretty different than the original. You will need to split your cells by spaces and do some loops

Comment: how many unique values are in column A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values you want to remove all have the pattern `TL_xxxx` you can use wildcards to replace them.

Ctrl-H to open the Find and Replace dialog, put `TL_????` into the `Find what` box and leave the `Replace with` box blank.

You may need a second pass to replace two spaces or two line breaks with just one.

Comment: That worked!  I had no idea you could use wild cards in excel.  Thank you!!